# Showing existence of cycles in regular graphs

Tags: graph-theory

I need to prove that in every graph $G$ with minimal degree $\delta \geq 2$ there's a cycle of length at least $\delta+1$. I think that it's enough to show the result for $\delta$-regular graphs, but I have no idea how to start.  Any hints (not full solutions) or ways to approach it will be appreciated.

Comment: [Linked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/699867/let-g-be-a-graph-of-minimum-degree-k1-show-that-g-has-a-cycle-of-length?rq=1)

Answer (score 3):

'Would you tell me, please, which way I ought to go from here?'

'That depends a good deal on where you want to get to,' said the Cat.

'I don't much care where — ' said Alice.

'Then it doesn't matter which way you go,' said the Cat.

'— so long as I get *somewhere*,' Alice added as an explanation.

'Oh, you're sure to do that,' said the Cat, 'if you only walk long enough.'

Comment: This is one of the best hints I have ever seen. +1