# Show that G has a path of $\delta(G)$ for minimum degree greater than 2

Tags: graph-theory

Let G be a graph with minimum degree $\ge2$.
 The minimum degree of G is denoted by $\delta(G)$

Show that G has a path of $\delta(G)$

Ok first we know that the graph must at least be a triangle cycle because the minimum degree is greater than 2.

So let P be a be a max path from $v1,v2,...,vk$ it must have all of the neighbors of v1 to be a max path and all the neighbors of v1 are $\delta(G)$

Hence the max path must be $P=\delta(g)+1$ the one is the graph the plus 1 coming from the $v1vk$ edge the final edge.

I am not sure this is true I am new to the graph theory.

Comment: I assume your sentence "Prove that the cirucumference of a graph denoted..." is incomplete?

Comment: Probably it is not necessary that a maximal path contains all neighbors of $v_1$.

Comment: Just copied from the Related tab: [Let $G$ be a graph of minimum degree $k>1$. Show that $G$ has a cycle of length at least $k+1$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/699867/let-g-be-a-graph-of-minimum-degree-k1-show-that-g-has-a-cycle-of-length?rq=1)

Comment: Oh yeah I the circumference of a graph I deleted that part I made a mistake there.